# Error handling in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will add a car, it will also need to have error handling which will accept a driver number (different table)
and if it does not exist it will raise an error.

I have no idea how to approach this, any suggestions or example of similar code would be much appreciated,

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something along the lines of

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tableDrivers WHERE DriverNumber = @DriverNumber_IN) 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR('MEANINGFULSTRING TO HANDLE IN CLIENT CODE', 18, 1)
        RETURN
    END
```

This way you exit the storedprocedure, and whatever your client code that calls the stored procedure you'll get to see the MEANINGFULSTRING TO HANDLE IN CLIENT CODE, such as in a SQL Exception were you to use ADO.Net in C#

Comment: nice thank you, btw what does the 18,1 mean?

Comment: @Vlad11 18 is the severity of the error, 18 usually means that the problem can't be fixed the the user. 1 is the state of the error and its up to the person writing the error handling what they want it to be. You can check out the documentation on RAISERROR here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx